# Base units in CGS and technic systems

Tags: conventions, dimensional-analysis, units, metrology

What are the base units in the CGS and the technical system of units? Is there not seven? How could it be that what is fundamental in any system is not in other?

By the way, how many minimal "base units" do we need in any system of units?

It seems there is no clear list of basic units in the above systems (unlike the SI) in the bibliography (Wikipedia, physics books talking about the CGS system,...). I mean, I found out that there is no "list" of basic gaussian/cgs/technical system of units (are there 6,7, 17,...basic units?).

Comment: What is the “technical system of units”?

Comment: *in the bibliography* In *what* bibliography?

Comment: @Ghoster I clarified that point in the question. Thanks!

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean by "the technical system of units". SI has seven basic units because one (candela) has to do with how the human eye works. Another (mole) is just a scale factor. Yet another (kelvin) is essentially energy multiple by a scale factor. That leaves four, and this raises the question of whether charge is fundamental.

Comment: Technical system of units is the one with kiloponds or mass-kg in its base units...Engineering system is called in my country...